# What is the complexity of this algorithm and is there a possibility to improve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

This is the algorithm of this problem: Write a function that takes two arrays as input, each array contains a list of A-Z; your program should return True if the
2nd array is a subset of 1st array, or False if not.

```
# Python 3 program to find whether an array

def isSubset(arr1, arr2):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(arr2)):
        if(arr2[i] not in arr1):
            return False
    return True
     
arr1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
arr2 = ["C", "A", "A"]

if(isSubset(arr1, arr2)):
    print("arr2[] is a subset of arr1[] ")
else:
    print("arr2[] is not a subset of arr1[]")
```

Comment: Hi, Please read [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) to learn how to ask a good homework question.

Comment: The complexity is `O(n^2)` as `arr2[i] not in arr1` requires `O(n)` runtime.

Comment: I guess its O(n²) because you have a loop in a loop.

Comment: I believe the output for your `arr1` and `arr2` should be `arr2[] is not a subset of arr1[]`?

Comment: It's O(M*N) where M and N are the size of the inputs. You could do O(max(M, N)) if you used a different data structure that could check membership faster. Here, `set` would be the choice, python having already implemented the less-than operator for the subset relation: `set(arr2) <= set(arr1)` (note, `<=` is subset, `<` is propert subset)

Comment: I never thought about it but I think that's right @juanpa.arrivillaga, O(n²) would be only true of M.length = N.length which isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of your algorithm is `O(n*k)`, where `n` and `k` is length of arrays. You have one loop inside another one and search in the list takes `O(n)`

```
for i in range(len(arr2)):
     if(arr2[i] not in arr1)  # inner loop because of `in` with `O(n)` complexity
```

You can optimize your algorithm:

```
s = set()
for el in arr1:
  s.add(el)

for el in arr2:
  if el not in s:
     return False

return True
```

In this case the time complexity is `O(n+k)`, where `n` and `k` is length of arrays. Search in the `set` (and `dict` has `O(1)` time complexity).

But is this case you need an additional space for `set`. So new  algorithm has `O(n)` space complexity while original one - `O(1)`.

Comment: is `["A", "A", "A"]` a subset of `["A"]`?

Comment: @LearningMathematics 
For example:
isSubset([A,B,C,D,E], [A,E,D]) = true
isSubset([A,B,C,D,E], [A,D,Z]) = false
isSubset([A,D,E], [A,A,D,E]) = true

Comment: @Achref so an array of a larger size can be a subset of an array of a smaller size?

Comment: @LearningMathematics no that is impossible by definition. It can be a superset. Or maybe a portion of that large array can be a subset, but not the full array.

Comment: @TheFool I thought the same, but I guess it is this is what the OP intends to do.

Comment: `s = set(arr1)` would be shorter and quicker.

Comment: `s = ()` creates an empty tuple. I don't think there's any way to make an empty set using a literal in python, so you need `s = set()`.

Comment: `set(arr1).issuperset(arr2)` is a one-liner

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write the code for you because it is a homework question. I will describe an algorithm for you and you should implement it yourself.

Take your `arr1` and `arr2` as an example, preprocess `arr1` first by storing the number of occurrences of `A-Z`. So for your `arr1`, you should get:

```
"A": 1,
"B": 1,
"C": 1,
"D": 1,
"E": 1,
"F": 1,
"G": 0,
...
```

Now do th same for `arr2`, you should get:

```
"A": 2,
"B": 0,
"C": 1,
"D": 0,
...
```

Now compare the value of `A-Z` in these two lists, if any correponding value for `arr2` is larger than `arr1`, your program should return `false`, otherwise `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code's time complexity is **O(M*N)** - *as you are searching if there is a matching item in `arr1` for every item in `arr2`.*

The better way would be to use `Count` Arrays and solve it in Linear Time and Constant Space.

Complexities of this Code:

- **Time Complexity: O(M + N)**
- **Space Complexity: O(26)**

```
arr1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
arr2 = ["C", "A"]

def check(arr1, arr2):
    c1 = [0]*26
    c2 = [0]*26
    a = ord('A')
    for i in arr1:
        if c1[ord(i) - a] == 0:
            c1[ord(i) - a] += 1

    for j in arr2:
        if c2[ord(i) - a] == 0:
            c2[ord(j) - a] += 1

    for i in range(len(c1)):
        if c2[i] > c1[i]:
            return 'Not a Subset'
    return 'Subset'


    
print(check(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"], ["C", "A"]))
print(check(["B"], ["A", "B"]))
print(check(["A"], ["A", "A"]))
print(check(["A","B"], []))
print(check([], []))
```

```
Subset
Not a Subset
Subset
Subset
Subset
```